# Problem Parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: json, jquery

Hi wondering if someone can help me - I am trying to make a Ajax call to retrieve some json data. The data comes back fine but I am unable to retrieve any of the data. The JSON I am working with is :

```
    {
 "X_lconn_userid" : "dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e",
 "uid": "JonathanPopoola",
 "key": "06b4b957-4941-4d68-80c4-83306c551740",
 "fn": "Jonathan Popoola",
 "photo": "https://dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com/profiles/photo.do?key=06b4b957-4941-4d68-80c4-83306c551740&lastMod=1295913640000",
 "adr": {"work": {"locality": "", "region": "", 
  "country_name": ""}},
 "tel": {"work": "0207 293 3000"},
 "email": {  "internet": "Jonathan.Popoola@trinitymirror.com", "X_notes": ""},
 "title": "",
 "employeeTypeDesc": "", 
 "org": "", 
 "X_building_name": "Canary Wharf",
 "X_building_floor": "23",
 "X_office": "",
 "X_blogUrl": "",
 "X_inDirectory": "true",

 "X_bizCardShowPhoto": true,
 "X_bizCardSTAwareness": false,
 "X_bizCardSecureSTAwareness": true,
  "X_bizCardLocation": {  "unsecure": "" , "secure":  ""},
  "X_bizCardSTInputType": "email",
 "X_bizCardSTStatusMsg": true,
 "X_STChatAction": true,
 "X_STCallAction": true,
 "X_bizCardServiceLinks": [{"name":"blogs","js_eval":"generalrs.label_personcard_blogslink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/blogs\/roller-ui\/blog\/dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"},{"name":"quickr","js_eval":"generalrs.label_personcard_quickrlink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/quickr\/allfiles\/people\/Jonathan.Popoola@trinitymirror.com"},{"name":"profiles","js_eval":"generalrs.label_personcard_profilelink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/profiles\/html\/simpleSearch.do?searchFor=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e&searchBy=userid"},{"name":"activities","js_eval":"generalrs.label_personcard_activitieslink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/activities\/service\/html\/mainpage#dashboard%2Cmyactivities%2Cuserid%3Ddbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e%2Cname%3DJonathan Popoola"},{"name":"dogear","js_eval":"generalrs.label_personcard_dogearlink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/dogear\/html?userid=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"},{"name":"communities","js_eval":"generalrs.label_personcard_communitieslink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/communities\/service\/html\/allcommunities?userid=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"},{"name":"wikis","js_eval":"generalrs.label.personcard.wikislink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/wikis\/home\/search?uid=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e&name=Jonathan Popoola"},{"name":"files","js_eval":"generalrs.label_personcard_fileslink","href":"https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/files\/app\/person\/dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"}],
 "X_allowEvalLabel": true
}
```

The code I am currently using is:

```
    function getvCard (uid) {
   //will need to build url and include uid for live server !
   $.ajax ({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http:\/\/cw-epuip-d01.tm-gnet.com:10040/EnhancedTheme/themes/html/Enhanced/js/modules/jpopoola.json", 
   dataType: "application/json",
   timeout: 10000,
   success: function(data){
    console.log(data.photo);

   },
   error: function(e, xhr) {
    console.log("error" + e);
   }
  });
```

Could anyone shed some light how I can access a item within the JSON data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataType: "application/json",
```

should be

```
dataType: "json",
```

..and there is no need to escape the `//` within the url.

Comment: ok cheers but the data type would'nt work with just json - kept hitting the error call back